# How to perform a simple update using Subsonic ,in Visual STudio(c#)

Tags: visual-studio, subsonic

I have a very simple update.According to the ID of the table,I want to set a boolean column to true.The problem is that I my knowledge to subsonic is like 'pitch black'.

I have done the following but it does not work.

```
new SubSonic.Update(FundReturn.Schema).Set(FundReturn.Columns.IsDeleted).EqualTo(1)
          .Where(FundReturn.Columns.FundId).IsEqualTo(Convert.ToInt32(row.RecordID)).Execute();
```

The above line seems very logical,however it does not work.

I would appreciate any help given

Comment: You can print out the SQL that is being generated by SubSonic to give you a little more information.  Here's an example how: dim q as SubSonic.SqlQuery = new SubSonic.Update...; Debug.Print(q.ToString())

Answer (score 2):

Guessing here, but instead of setting IsDeleted to '1' like it would appear in the database, set it to 'true' because the property you are working with is probably interpreted as a boolean in the generated code. SubSonic will automatically handle this and the RecordId conversion for you.

```
new SubSonic.Update(FundReturn.Schema).Set(FundReturn.Columns.IsDeleted).EqualTo(true)
     .Where(FundReturn.Columns.FundId).IsEqualTo(row.RecordID).Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Woah there....  it's a lot simpler that you might be thinking....

```
var objActiveRecord = SomeActiveRecordType.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == iId);
objActiveRecord.SomeBoolProperty = true;
objActiveRecord.Update();
```

Comment: this is assuming you are using the SubSonic code generation templates.